# State changed before displaying swal message in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<b-card-text class="mb-0">
    Success
</b-card-text>
<b-form-checkbox
   checked="true"
   class="custom-control-success"
   name="check-button"
   switch
   @change="changeStatus"
/>

    changeStatus() {
      this.$swal({
        icon: "question",
        text: "Change Status?",
        buttonsStyling: false,
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: "OK",
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
          // handle code
        }
      });
    },
```

I am making checkbox in vuejs. When I click on the status to switch the status, it shows a `swal` saying `Change Status`. The problem I have is: When I just press status, a message `swal` appears, the status has been changed. I want if I press `Ok` the status will change, but if I press cancel it will stay the same, Thanks

Comment: could you provide some more code to us or create a fiddle? because now it's not really clear where your problem is in the code..

Comment: @B0BBY I have corrected the question, when I click change status, `swall` shows up. I didn't do anything but the status was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your switch is not reactive value
checked default is `true` right, when its change it will be `false`

you just need make it reactive

example:
`data():{ arr:[{name: "test", status: true}, {name: "test2", status: false}]}`

make it reactive

```
<table id="example-1">
  <tr v-for="item in arr" :key="item.name">
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    <td>
    <b-form-checkbox
       checked="item.status" <--- this make it reactive
       class="custom-control-success"
       name="check-button"
       switch
       @change="changeStatus"
    />
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```